# avoid "_X000D" due to line breaks

Tags: excel, vba

when copied multiline text from texttbox of an userform to an excel cell something like *x000d* is getting added at the end of each line.when i googled it i understood it is due to line break .but line break is really necessary for me.this

```
cells(i,"A").value = textbox1.value
```

i would like to get multi-line data in cell without "*x000d* "

Comment: try `cells(i."A").value = replace(textbox1.value,vbCrLf,"")` - where you're replacing vbCrLf (x000d or carriagereturn + linefeed) with empty string

Comment: thanks for the answer .will try it